# Find the integral curves of the given vector field.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

The vector field is as follows:

$X_{(x,y)} = x \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} - y \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} = \begin{bmatrix} x \\y \end{bmatrix}$.

I know that to find integral curves, you need to solve a differential equation. So here, I would take a derivative of $X$, but I am not completely sure of what to do. With other integral curve computations, I'm usually given some initial conditions. Tips on how to get started would be very helpful. That's really all I'm asking for here. I can do the rest of the math myself. I'm just struggling setting it up.

Comment: $x'(t)=x$ and $y'(t)=-y$.

Comment: And that is because $X|_U=\alpha_1(\partial/\partial x_1)+...+\alpha_n(\partial/\partial x_n)$ and if $\gamma$ is integral curve of vector field $X$ then $d\gamma_t(\partial/\partial t)_t=X_{\gamma(t)}$ and after a little bit computation you will find $\alpha_i(\gamma(t))=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} (x_i \circ \gamma)$ where $x_i$ are coordinate function in neighbourhood $U$ of some point $p \in M$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solve for $x,y$ the equations
$$\dot x=x\\ \dot y=-y$$ and so the integral curve would be $$\alpha(t)=
(x(t),y(t))$$

Comment: This is very nicely done. Thank you very much for the tip. :)

Comment: Glad to help out